# React-google-login popup close immediately

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, react-google-login

I use `React-google-login` to sign up and log in with a google account in my app
I use a client id to test it.
this is my login component import:

```
<GoogleLogin
 icon={false}
 className="input-rounded d-flex"
 clientId="....."
 onSuccess={() => handleGoogleSignUp}
 onFailure={() => handleGoogleSignUp}
 cookiePolicy={"single_host_origin"}
>
  <div
    role="button"
    className="m-0 google-signin d-flex"
  >
    img src={vector} alt="vector" className="me-2" />
   <div>Sign up with Google</div>
  </div>
</GoogleLogin>
```

this is my function:

```
const handleFailure = (err) => {
    console.log(err);
};

const handleSucsess = (res) => {
     console.log(res);
}
```

but when click on the google button the popup close immediately
and I can't choose one account
can anybody help me?